# How do I resolve a promise using try, catch, .then chaining, and async await in JS?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fetch, try-catch

I am making a get request from the client to the server. I have confirmed it fetches data and sends it back to the client successfully. However, in the .then chaining, when I console.log res.json(), it says the promise is still pending.

I have tried adding async, await and/or the try, catch phrase as you will see below in the code.

I have tried everything I know. Is there a way to solve this?

Here is the code of the client's get request logic using fetch:

```
let cache = {};

async function getMsg() {
    try { 
        await fetch('/api/getMsg')
        .then(res =>  {console.log(res.json()); return res.json()})
        .then(data => {
            console.log('got data', data);
            const list = document.createElement('li');
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            const ul = document.getElementById('message-list');

            // data is an array whose elements are message objects
            data.forEach((obj)=> {
                if (!cache.obj._id) {

                    list.innerText(obj.message);
                    button.innerText('Delete');
                    button.setAttribute('class', 'del');

                    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        fetch(`/api/${obj._id}`)
                            .then(res => res.json())
                            .then(data => {
                                window.alert(`Message with id of ${data} has been deleted!`);
                            })
                    });
                    document.querySelector('body').append(ul);
                    ul.append(list)
                    ul.append(button);
                    cache.obj._id = obj.message;
                }
            });
        })
    } catch {
        (err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

The error message on the console:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way here is not to use async-await at all. like this:

```js
let cache = {};

function getMsg() {
    fetch('/api/getMsg')
    .then(res =>  {console.log(res.json()); return res.json()})
    .then(data => {
        console.log('got data', data);
        const list = document.createElement('li');
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        const ul = document.getElementById('message-list');

        // data is an array whose elements are message objects
        data.forEach((obj)=> {
            if (!cache.obj._id) {

                list.innerText(obj.message);
                button.innerText('Delete');
                button.setAttribute('class', 'del');

                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    fetch(`/api/${obj._id}`)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            window.alert(`Message with id of ${data} has been deleted!`);
                        })
                });
                document.querySelector('body').append(ul);
                ul.append(list)
                ul.append(button);
                cache.obj._id = obj.message;
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

but if want to use the try-catch and async-await syntax you can try it like this:

```js
let cache = {};

async function getMsg() {
    try { 
        let res = await fetch('/api/getMsg');
        let data = await res.json();
        console.log('got data', data);
        const list = document.createElement('li');
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        const ul = document.getElementById('message-list');

        // data is an array whose elements are message objects
        data.forEach((obj)=> {
            if (!cache.obj._id) {

                list.innerText(obj.message);
                button.innerText('Delete');
                button.setAttribute('class', 'del');

                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    fetch(`/api/${obj._id}`)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            window.alert(`Message with id of ${data} has been deleted!`);
                        })
                });
                document.querySelector('body').append(ul);
                ul.append(list)
                ul.append(button);
                cache.obj._id = obj.message;
            }
        });

    } catch {
        (err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

I think this should work

Comment: Thank you very much. Originally I had it set up as your first solution, but still got the same error. When I try your second solution, no error is shown. However, the console.log on the 3rd line of 'try' phrase doesn't even show up on the console. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Is it not showing anything in the console? or just not showing the data?

Comment: Not showing anything! It's really odd.. seems like it is awaiting forever because it is not hitting the console.log('got data', data)..

Comment: and can you check the network tab on the developer tools and see if there something wrong there?

Comment: yes, res is working: Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3434/api/getMsg", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3434/api/getMsg"
------------------
In networks tab, I don't see any status in the 400s or red graphs!

Comment: is it possible that your response content-type is not JSON?

Comment: I am fetching from MongoDB. It is an array whose elements are objects. The router sends back to the client through the code ' res.send(200).json(res.locals.getMsg);'
Therefore, I think it should be JSON.

Comment: on the network tab, when you click on this request, can you see the response data properly?

Comment: in the waterfall graph in networks tab, all graphs are green, but 'getMsg' green graph starts pretty late(after all other requests) and there is a vertical red line at the point where getMsg response graph starts! 
response header:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: wow, it was a problem in the server. I was using res.send(200) or res.sednStatus, but when I use res.status, the console.log('got data', data) shows... thank you for your help!!!!!!!